# Is it valid HTML to have more than one label targetting an item?

Tags: html, label

Is there anything wrong with the following block of HTML?

```
<label for="days">Every</label>
<input type="number" id="days" name="days" />
<label for="days">Days</label>
```

I can't find anything that says you can't have more than one label, but every example I find only has one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Mozilla documentation it appears that it's legitimate:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

> One input can be associated with multiple labels.

Answer (score 0):

Reinforcing reading..
[label-for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLLabelElement/htmlFor)

Answer (score 0):

Should be valid w3c validator does not show error.
[https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea][1]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <title>Is it valid HTML to have more than one label targetting an item? - Stack Overflow</title>
    </head>
    <body >
        <label for="days">Every</label>
        <input type="number" id="days" name="days" />
        <label for="days">Days</label>
    </body>
</html>
```